# Setup faster on-machine wcf named pipe bindings without security?

Tags: wcf, named-pipes

I am running a web site that has an on-the-machine wcf named pipe binding between the ASP.NET site and an API. However, since starting up new connections (named pipes) takes some time, I am thinking turning of the security negotiation will improve the speed.

1. Is there really a good reason to have the security when the networking is on the same machine? Can I turn it off?
2. How do I turn it off?

Comment: What makes you think that the performance bottleneck lies in the communication protocol?

Comment: I ran the site when each method created a new connection to the service - it quickly became a problem. I then changed to that the main page creates 1 connection per page view (instead of ~7-8), it solved much of the problems. But when the site has the highest load, there is still a problem.

Comment: That tells you that the service takes a long time to respond to requests. It doesn't necessarily tell you *what* is taking up most of total round-trip time. Is the service doing some expensive operations on each request, like for example opening up a database connection?

Comment: True. Interestingly the CPU is quite low during that time - so the actual operations are not that low. (I have checked for dead locks (in db)).